# Storing children of Firebase Database in an array

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have set up a Firebase database that has a parent and many different children. I am attempting to save all of the children's keys into an array that I can access elsewhere in the code.

```
// Used to get the children
rootRef.child(partyName).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
    var newItems = [FIRDataSnapshot]()

    for item in snapshot.children {
        newItems.append(item as! FIRDataSnapshot)

    }

    if let snapDict = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject]{

        for each in snapDict{
            let keyID = each.key

            saves.append(keyID)
        }
    }

})
```

Unfortunately, most of the "solutions" that I have found online simply print the retrieved data or add it to a Table View. I simply want all the children to be saved in an array that I can access later. Is this possible? If so, how would I do it?

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't make sense to refetch the values again. Use a dictionary to store the key and value. Thats way you can call keys property to get keys in array format.

Comment: I am not sure what the issue is  here.. Are you not able to get the keys in the array??? Also update your question with your JSON tree

Answer (score 0):

The proper way of storing the retrieved data is to store the key-value pairs in an `NSDictionary` or a Swift `Dictionary`. As Sachin Vas said, it makes no sense to store just the keys because then you'd have no relation back to the values.

Nevertheless, to answer your question, the code you provided in your question does what you're asking. If `saves` is a global or static array in some class, it would be accessible globally throughout your application and would contain all the retrieved keys.

The right way of storing the retrieved data would work just the same way, except `saves` would be a `Dictionary`.

```
rootRef.child(partyName).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

    if let snapDict = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
        saves = snapDict    // where saves is declared as Dictionary<String, AnyObject> 
    }

})
```